# The Validation Accuracy and Loss is not chaning on my custom CNN

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence, classification

I have downloaded following Cat and Dog pictures from:  https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/abhinavnayak/catsvdogs-transformed.
Code:

```py
import torch
from torch import nn
from PIL import Image
from torchvision import transforms, datasets
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
import random
from torch.nn import functional as F

class MyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data, labels):
        self.data = data
        self.labels = labels

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        sample = {
            'data': torch.tensor(self.data[index]),
            'label': torch.tensor(self.labels[index])
        }
        return sample

#####Image loading and transform#####

transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((96, 96)),
    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),  
    transforms.RandomRotation(10),  
    transforms.ColorJitter(brightness=0.2, contrast=0.2, saturation=0.2, hue=0.1),  
    transforms.ToTensor()
])

X = []
y = []

for i in range(1, 1001):
    img1 = Image.open(r"C:\Users\GameO\Desktop\DS\ml\train_transformed\dog" + str(i) + r".jpg")
    img2 = Image.open(r"C:\Users\GameO\Desktop\DS\ml\train_transformed\cat" + str(i) + r".jpg")

    for _ in range(5):  # Create  augmented versions for each image
        X.append(transform(img1))
        y.append(torch.tensor(0.0))

        X.append(transform(img2))
        y.append(torch.tensor(1.0))

X = torch.stack(X)
y = torch.stack(y)

###shuffle data ####

def preprocess(X, y):
    length = len(y)

    indices = list(range(length))
    random.shuffle(indices)
   
    train_indices = indices[:8000]
    val_indices = indices[8000:]
    
    X_train, y_train = X[train_indices], y[train_indices]
    X_val, y_val = X[val_indices], y[val_indices]

    return X_train, y_train, X_val, y_val

training_X, training_y, val_X,val_y = preprocess(X,y)

X = None
y = None


training_set = MyDataset(training_X, training_y)
val_set = MyDataset(val_X, val_y)

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=training_set, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)
val_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=val_set, batch_size=32, shuffle=False)

###Model definition

class CNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,lr,num_classes,weight_decay=0,dropout=0):
        super().__init__()
        self.lr = lr
        self.weight_decay = weight_decay
        
        self.net = nn.Sequential(
            nn.LazyConv2d(32,kernel_size=(3,3),padding=1),nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2,2),stride=2),
            nn.LazyConv2d(32,kernel_size=(3,3),padding=1),nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2,2),stride=2),
            nn.Flatten(),
            nn.LazyLinear(32),
            nn.LazyLinear(num_classes))

    
    def forward(self,X):
        return F.sigmoid(self.net(X))

    def loss(self,y_hat,y):
        return F.binary_cross_entropy(y_hat,y)
        
    def configure_optimizer(self):
        return torch.optim.SGD(params=self.parameters(), lr=self.lr,weight_decay=self.weight_decay)

####custom training loop#####

device = torch.device("cuda")
model = CNN(lr=0.001,num_classes=1,weight_decay=0)
model.to(device)
optimizer = model.configure_optimizer()
max_epochs = 10

for epoch in range(max_epochs):
    epoch_loss = 0
    
    for i,batch in enumerate(train_loader):
        
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        X,y = batch["data"].to(device),batch["label"].to(device)
        y_hat = model(X)
        y = y.unsqueeze(1)
        
        loss = model.loss(y_hat,y)
        loss.backward()
        epoch_loss+=loss.item()
        optimizer.step()
    
    print(f"{epoch}.Epoch-Loss: {epoch_loss/(len(train_loader)*32)}")
    val_acc = 0
    for batch in val_loader:
        with torch.no_grad():
            X,y = batch["data"].to(device),batch["label"]
            y_hat = model(X)
            val_acc += ((y_hat.cpu().argmax(1))==y).sum()
        

    print(f"{epoch}.Val-acc: {val_acc/(len(val_loader)*32)}")
```

With the Code, my CNN converges after the first Epoch at a relatively low Epoch-Loss around 0.001-0.008 and a Validation Accuarcy of around 47-50%. Even if I change the learning rate or the size of the filters or the amount of Conv2D Layers or anything else, the Model still converges after the first epoch. At the beginning I had only 2000 Images, now I've augmented them, to get more, but nothing changes.
I can't quite understand where the problem is, since I've watched a almost equivalent implementation of this model on the cat/dog dataset, and everything worked as expected.